# Sybase client/server setup

Tags: powerbuilder, sap-ase

At the place where i work, the client program is actually a shortcut for one exe file locate in the intranet. All the users practically using the same exe file.

Is this the correct way of setup an client/server environment?
Does this results in high CPU usage?

I always believe that client program should be installed in every user's PC.
But the program need an .ini file which everyone can easily see the content. (database username, password, etc.)
What is the safe way if I were to install the program in every PC.

We always have problems such as the program hangs, slow connection, etc.
Do you think the way we setup the environment is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A network installation is not globally "incorrect", although it can, as you point out, cause problems when you have a less-than-reliable network infrastructure. PowerBuilder has also had some bugs (in specific versions, you don't mention yours) that only manifest themselves or are more pronounced when executables are on a network resource. I'm not sure a network installation would be my first recommendation, but I'd hesitate to call it "wrong."

Access to global information is a challenge when you don't network deploy. Most apps I've worked on either deployed this information on installation, or shared it through the database. (Never had an app that shared user name and password, though... *shudder*... I suppose there may be *some* cases.) Deploying on installation to local files either assumes the information is non-volatile (or at least not more often updated than releases) or that the information will be synced with a network accessible location on a regular basis. There are several utilities you can use to sync these resources, or you can code it in your app.

As for pinning your problems on network installation, we don't have enough information to safely do that. (It's safe to say that hangs and "slow connections" can occur with local installations.) You'll have to do the legwork yourself to get evidence to that end.

Good luck,

Terry